# list doesnt display inline IE?

Tags: css, xhtml

The code below works fine in firefox, but the list doesnt display in-line with IE.

```html
<div id="nav">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">4</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">5</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```css
#nav
{
    width: 800px;
    padding: 0px; 
    margin: 0 auto; 
    list-style-type: none;  
}

#nav ul li a 
{
    font-size: 18px;    
    text-decoration: none;   
    text-align: center;  
    color: #ffffff;   
    background-color: #003366;   
    padding: 20px;
    list-style: none;
    float: left; 
    list-style-type: none; 
    line-height: 5px; 
    display: inline; 
    margin-left: 5px; 
}

#nav ul li a:hover 
{
    background-color: #ccc;
}
```

Also in IE the bullet points still display?

Comment: Please post the correct HTML fragment. There should be a <ul> or <ol> element at least.

Comment: Sorry the code display went abit funny, fixed now

Comment: Made it even easier to read ...

Comment: An article about css inline elements. Fixed my problems with IE http://blog.mozilla.org/webdev/2009/02/20/cross-browser-inline-block/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
#nav
{
    width: 800px;
    padding: 0px; 
    margin: 0 auto; 
    list-style-type: none;  
}

#nav ul li
{
    text-align: center;  
    background-color: #003366;   
    list-style: none;
    list-style-type: none; 
    margin-left: 5px; 
    display: inline; 
    float: left; 
}

#nav ul li a 
{
    font-size: 18px;    
    text-decoration: none;   
    color: #ffffff;   
    line-height: 5px; 
    padding: 20px;
    display: inline-block; 
}

#nav ul li a:hover
{
    background-color: #ccc;  
}
```

Comment: Thanks that works, apart from the hover...it doesnt fill the whole block just the part over the text

Comment: @Elliott: I didn't test the earlier codes, this edit should work.

Answer (score 1):

I think you problem is that you put the CSS on the #nav ul li a, and this should be on the #nav ul li element.

Check [this article](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/taminglists/) for a very good explanation on list-styling. The section about inline lists should be of particular interest to you.

Answer (score 1):

You are putting list-style-type on your div but not on your ul element. list-style-type is not inherited from non-list items in IE.